# Display several 2d image as a stack in R

Tags: r, powerbi

How to display stack of several  2d images to form as 3d image in R ? If anyone can share the code with the example it would be very helpful.[enter link description here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=26m_W5ycA8L5gQaQ_YDYDw&ins=false&q=stack%20of%20images&oq=stack%20of%20images&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.12..35i39l3j0i67j0.1884.3874..6205...0.0..0.133.1048.11j1......0....1.........0i71j33i160j0i22i30j33i22i29i30.KEul4Y_KL9o#imgrc=Io0xdRfSzQrIIM:)

Answer (score 2):

See the vignette for the `magick` package.
https://github.com/ropensci/magick/blob/master/vignettes/intro.Rmd

Under Image Vectors - Combining, it shows how to combine multiple layers with an offset. It sounds like you'd do something like:

```
library(magick)
combo <- image_composite(layer1, layer2, offset = "+0+50")
combo <- image_composite(combo , layer3, offset = "+0+50")
combo <- image_composite(combo , layer4, offset = "+0+50")
```

Comment: Hi Jon,                                                                                               Thanks for your kind reply.